# How to run a coroutine and wait for its result from a sync func

Tags: python, python-asyncio, flask-socketio, python-socketio, aiortc

I am trying to run a python [socketIO client](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html) along side a server. Basically when the server gets a `viewer` event, the client fires another connection to an upstream server. It then tries to establish a WebRTC connection based on [aiortc](https://aiortc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=candidate#aiortc.RTCIceCandidate).

```
# sio client 
sioClient = socketio.Client()

# sio server 
async_mode = None
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
sioServer = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    print("Get request '/'")
    return render_template('index.html')

@sioClient.on('connect')
def sio_connect():
    sioClient.emit('viewer', {'foo': 'bar'})
    print('proxy is connected to server, SID = ', sioClient.sid)


@sioClient.on('offer')
def sio_offer(broadcasterId,broadcasterDescription): 
    print("offer event")
    peerConnection = RTCPeerConnection()
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(broadcasterDescription)

    print("remoteDescription is ", peerConnection.remoteDescription)

@sioServer.on('viewer')
def handle_viewer_event(arg1):
    print('received args: ' + arg1["data"])
    sioClient.connect('http://localhost:4000')
    print('proxy sid is', sioClient.sid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sioServer.run(app)
```

Currently the `@sioClient.on('connect')` works fine and successfully emits another 'viewer' event to the upstream server. However when an 'offer' event comes back, I get the below error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'RTCPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription' was never awaited
  peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(broadcasterDescription)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
remoteDescription is  None
```

I sort of understand this is because ['RTCPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription'](https://aiortc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=candidate#aiortc.RTCPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription) is an asynchronous coroutine, but I don't know how to wait for it synchronously.

I have tried to make `sio_offer` an asynchronous func like below:

```
@sioClient.on('offer')
async def sio_offer(broadcasterId,broadcasterDescription): 
    print("offer event")
    peerConnection = RTCPeerConnection()
    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(broadcasterDescription)

    print("remoteDescription is ", peerConnection.remoteDescription)
```

But the whole block doesn't execute anymore upon an 'offer' event.
I've seen a few suggestions around [asyncio eventloop](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-eventloop.html). But I am a python beginner and got very confused...

It will be appreciated if anyone can shed a bit light! Thanks in advance!

Comment: aiortc is not compatible with sync Python. You have to write an asyncio application to use this library.

Comment: Hmmmm ok, seems I am on the wrong path totally. Thanks Miguel